# Need a good JavaScript uploader

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to upload files directly to Amazon S3. I have tried using [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) and [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/). Both have their merits. However, I've found both to be incompatible with older browser versions. Particularly IE 7, 8 and 9. I've also tested with Firefox 3.6. Really glitchy...

I looked at [FancyUpload](http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/), which is fully compatible with all A-Grade Browsers (Internet Explorer 6+, Opera 9, Firefox 1.5+ and Safari 3+) with Adobe Flash 9 and 10 player.

I've tried this uploader with Firefox 3.6 - 10, and IE 7, 8 and 9. NO PROBLEMS. The only thing, is that this is using MooTools, instead of jQuery. I know there are ways to integrate jQuery and MooTools. But before this approach, I would like to consider other options.

Does anyone know a good uploader script that is reliable (paid or unpaid)? Either in pure JS or jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [swfupload](http://swfupload.org/)

with jquery  [plugin](https://github.com/ifunk/swfupload-jquery-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a good candidate:

http://www.flajaxian.com/

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this one?

http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

Answer (score 0):

Seconding SWFUpload - very nicely implemented and easy to get up and running.